# Adding bevel and emboss to an SVG element?

Tags: css, svg, svg-filters, emboss

So I was wondering if it was possible to add bevel and emboss to an SVG element?

My CSS for my rectangle element is like this:

```
rect {
  fill: #e8e9eb;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  width: 70;
  height: 30;
}
```

and I was trying to add this CSS to it taken from [here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/snippets/emboss-effect-with-css):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.5), inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.25), inset 0 -3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
```

I believe the reason it isn't working is because it uses `fill` as opposed to a `background` but I'm not sure. Is there a way to do this while using the `fill` CSS style? If not, what would be the best way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want to use [SVG Filter effects](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html) to bevel arbitrary SVG Content.

Here's an example with two versions of a bevel:
http://jsfiddle.net/rcd5L/

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 -10 120 100">
  <filter id="Bevel" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="150%" height="150%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="3" result="blur"/>
    <feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="5" specularConstant="0.5" specularExponent="10" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
      <fePointLight x="-5000" y="-10000" z="20000"/>
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut2"/>
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="litPaint" />
  </filter>
  <filter id="Bevel2" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="-10%" y="-10%" width="150%" height="150%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="0.5" result="blur"/>
    <feSpecularLighting in="blur" surfaceScale="5" specularConstant="0.5" specularExponent="10" result="specOut" lighting-color="white">
      <fePointLight x="-5000" y="-10000" z="0000"/>
    </feSpecularLighting>
    <feComposite in="specOut" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="specOut2"/>
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="specOut2" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="1" k4="0" result="litPaint" />
  </filter>
  <rect width="100" height="40" filter="url(#Bevel)" />
  <rect y="50" width="100" height="40" filter="url(#Bevel2)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there a specific reason why the CSS option doesn't work on SVG? Just curious :)

Comment: @aug: box-shadow is defined to operate on the css boxes, and svg doesn't use these (yet anyway), there's no css layout happening inside svg content.

Comment: Very cool. For anyone curious, the filters don't work in IE9 http://i.imgur.com/DtLepQX.png —but do in IE10

Answer (score 2):

Also try using this if you want this kind of beveling

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-10 -10 120 100">
<filter id="filter1" >

          <feFlood flood-color="black" result="COLOR-red" />

          <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="0" in="SourceAlpha" result="STROKE_10" />

         <feConvolveMatrix order="8,8" divisor="1"
          kernelMatrix="1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" in="STROKE_10" result="BEVEL_20" />

          <feOffset dx="1" dy="1" in="BEVEL_0" result="BEVEL_25"/>
          <feComposite operator="out" in="BEVEL_25" in2="STROKE_10" result="BEVEL_30"/>
          <feComposite in="COLOR-red" in2="BEVEL_30" operator="in" result="BEVEL_40" />
          <feMerge result="BEVEL_50">
            <feMergeNode in="BEVEL_40" />
            <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
          </feMerge>



      </filter>

    <rect width="100" height="40" filter="url(#filter1)" />
    <path x="50" y="50" fill="#3182bd" d="M9.184850993605149e-15,-150A150,150 0 0,1 140.95389311788625,-51.30302149885031L0,0Z" filter="url(#filter1)"></path>
</svg>
```